# vsjitdebugger alternative?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

vsjitdebugger gets more annoying when i switched to windows 7. :(

i'm a commandline person (vim, msbuild and vsjitdebugger) when developing .NET. I'm looking for a better vsjitdebugger alternative that automatically attaches the application to visual studio (or any application that is less annoying than vsjitdebugger.)

TIA :)

Comment: If you think the vsjitdebugger can be replaced by a command line interface then you are not using it for what it was intended to do.  Mdbg.exe is a command line debugger for .net apps.

Comment: I usually work on more than one project and I usually open the main one in Visual Studio and copy all the necessary pdb's there. That's why I'm using vsjitdebugger to start the application and attach it to the main Visual Studio at the same time.

Comment: -1 *"better alternative"* and *"less annoying"* are about as vague as it ever gets. Please provide substantial requirements that vsjitdebugger.exe lacks.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx)

> To begin Just-In-Time debugging when
>   an error occurs
>
> In the Just-In-Time Debugging dialog
>   box, in the Possible Debuggers list,
>   click New instance of Visual Studio
>   2010 or click an instance of Visual
>   Studio 2010 that is already running.
>
> To use Visual Studio automatically for
>   all future crashes, click Set the
>   currently selected debugger as the
>   default.
>
> If you want to choose what types of
>   code you will be able to debug, click
>   Manually choose the debugging engines.
>   If you do not choose this option,
>   Visual Studio automatically selects
>   the appropriate debug engines for the
>   type of code in your program.
>
> Click OK.